# Filtro e paginação

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Desenvolvi uma pagina web que utiliza paginação e filtro, ambos feitos em `PHP`. O que faz com que depois de utilizar o filtro, e selecionar por exemplo a pagina 2, a informação será perdida, porque vai recarregar toda a informação.

Estive pesquisando e encontrei o seguinte:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q26WPjLqcOtS8p0mGF6b?p=preview

http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview

Será que é possível utilizar algo do gênero com ligação à base de dados ?

Como não sei o que usar ao certo será necessário a edição de tags e titulo

Codigo atual

filtro

```
  <FORM NAME ="form" METHOD ="POST" >




                   <select name="name" style='width:120px;' id="mySelect" >
                       <option value='' >Ordenar por:</option>
                       <option  value='cod_filme'>Mais recentes</option>
                       <option value='visualizacoes' >Mais vistos</option>
                   </select>



                   <select style='width:70px;' name="pesquisa" id="mySelect" >
                       <?php
                       error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
                       mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
                       mysql_select_db('trabalho_pratico');


                       $SQL = "SELECT * FROM ano";
                       $result = mysql_query($SQL);
                       print "<option value='' >Ano:</option>";
                       while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
                           print "<option value=" . $db_field['ano'] . ">" . $db_field['ano'] . "</option>";

                       }

                       ?>
                   </select>

                   <select name="categ" style='width:130px;' id="mySelect">
                       <?php
                       error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
                       mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
                       mysql_select_db('trabalho_pratico');


                       $SQL = "SELECT * FROM categoria";
                       $result = mysql_query($SQL);
                       print "<option value='' >Categoria:</option>";
                       while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
                           print "<option value=" . $db_field['categoria'] . ">" . $db_field['categoria'] . "</option>";

                       }

                       ?>
                   </select>
                   <td>
                       <input type='text' placeholder="Nome" name='procura'>
                   </td>
                   <input style='width:95px;'  type="submit" name="submitfiltro">
               </form>
```

Exibição do conteúdo filtrado com paginação

```
 if(($ano!="")&&($matr=="")&&($cat=="")&&($proc=="")){
                   $vari= "SELECT * FROM filme where ano=$ano";
                   $final_query="FROM filme where ano=$ano";
                   error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
                   mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
                   mysql_select_db('trabalho_pratico');
                   $maximo = 8;
                   $pagina = (isset($_GET["pagina"])) ? $_GET["pagina"] : null;
                   if($pagina == "") {
                       $pagina = "1";
                   }
                   $inicio = $pagina - 1;
                   $inicio = $maximo * $inicio;
                   $strCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'num_registros' $final_query";
                   $query = mysql_query($strCount);
                   $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                   $total = $row["num_registros"];
                   $SQL =$vari .  ' LIMIT '. $inicio. ' , '.$maximo;
                   $result = mysql_query($SQL);
                   while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
                       $img=$db_field['imagem'];
                       echo '<a href="conteudo.php?$op='.$img.'"><img src="' . $img . '"></a>';
                   }
                   $menos = $pagina - 1;
                   $mais = $pagina + 1;

                   $pgs = ceil($total / $maximo);
                   echo "<br>";
                   if($pgs > 1 ) {

                       echo "<br />";

                       // Mostragem de pagina
                       if($menos > 0) {
                           echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?pagina=$menos>anterior</a>&nbsp; ";
                       }

                       // Listando as paginas
                       for($i=1;$i <= $pgs;$i++) {
                           if($i != $pagina) {
                               echo " <a href='?pagina=".($i)."'>$i</a> | ";
                           } else {
                               echo " <strong>".$i."</strong> | ";
                           }
                       }

                       if($mais <= $pgs) {
                           echo " <a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?pagina=$mais>próxima</a>";
                       }
                   }
```

Conteúdo exibido depois de filtrar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando selecciono a pagina seguinte na paginação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Explique, o que você quer fazer realmente? Precisa enviar as informações do filtro para outra página?

Comment: nao o que tenho é uma pagina onde aparecem noticias e essa pagina tem paginação, o problema é que ao colocar o filtro que tambem é em php a informaçao ao trocar para pagina 2 perde-se

Comment: a página 2 que você diz, é a a segunda página da paginação? Ou uma outra página?

Comment: Sim tem como fazer, utilizar o SQL de **LIMIT** (Ler o tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) para trabalhar dele e fazer o resultado php. Exemplo: `SELECT * FROM  CADASTRO LIMIT 0 , 20` 0 é inicio, 20 é linha... proximo dele 21, 20 e proximo 41, 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ideia de paginação com filtros é você "guardar" qual filtro o usuário selecionou para quando ele clicar em outras páginas, o filtro não se perca.

**Um exemplo prático**

Digamos que eu tenha um select contendo os seguintes valores:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Filtro padrão por id</option>
  <option value="2">Filtro por A-Z</option>
  <option value="3">Filtro por Z-A</option>
</select>
```

Ao clicar em um deles, a lista é ordenada com esse valor.

Já na paginação, obrigatóriamente você deve além de informar a página, o filtro que atualmente está selecionado.

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">Pagina 1 e Filtro código ${De acordo com oq tiver na sessão}</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Pagina 2 e Filtro código ${De acordo com oq tiver na sessão}</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Pagina 3 e Filtro código ${De acordo com oq tiver na sessão}</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Pagina 4 e Filtro código ${De acordo com oq tiver na sessão}</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Pagina 5 e Filtro código ${De acordo com oq tiver na sessão}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi. O que estás a referir é no href alem do n da pagina devera ter uma variavel com valor do filtro?

Comment: @saimita As tag html são só uma exemplificação da idéia, você deve adaptar a idéia do modo que você está desenvolvendo em seu sistema :) . Sim, deve ter o valor do filtro junto com a página.

Comment: Só tenho um problema, ao filtrar a informação continua na mesma pagina, se por exemplo estiver na pagina dois e filtrar por ano vai aparecer o conteúdo filtrado mas na pagina dois de certa maneira ao clicar no submit vou ter de conseguir alterar a variável pagina que está no link para 1

Comment: @saimita Adapta pra quando tu selecionar outro filtro, resetar toda a página, voltando pro fluxo inicial :)

Comment: @saimita Te indico visitar alguma loja online e ver como eles fazem esse esquema. Por exemplo a store.xbox tem isso bem visivelmente.

Comment: coloquei uma variável ao iniciar a pagina que faz com que verifique se o submit do filtro foi selecionado ou nao dando asim um valor para cada situação. Verificando-se que o filtro foi seleccionado a pagina será 1. Obrigado pela ajuda prestada